# how to use SIGSEGV when trying to use memmove in c?

Tags: c

Im having an issue with memmove. I run this code through a visualizer and im getting a SIGSEGV error.

```
int main() {
  char *src;
  src = "this is a message, this is a new message";
  memmove(src, &(src[18]), 21);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you really asking _how to use SIGSEGV_? The answer would be with a signal handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src` is a pointer to the string created by a string literal. You aren't allowed to modify that. You are allowed to modify the contents of arrays, so create an array that contains the string as follows:

```
char src[] = "this is a message, this is a new message";
```

Also, assuming you want to end up with `this is a new message`, you're starting one too soon (`src[18]` is a the space before `this`), and you're stopping two too soon (you aren't including the final `e` or the string-terminating NUL).

```
          1         2         3         4     first to include = 19
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890     first to exclude = 41
this is a message, this is a new message␀     length = 41 - 19 = 22
```

As such, you should be using the following:

```
memmove(src, &(src[19]), 22);
```

or

```
memmove(src, src+19, 22);
```